# Passing data from one page to another

Tags: javascript

Pls can anybody give me the clue of how to pass data from one page(test1.html) to another page(test2.html) and then later pass the previous 2 pages(test1 and test2.html) to a new page called last.html using javascript not php cos it is a local app. tanx

Comment: QueryString or just use a form

Comment: Can you append the URL.? I mean would appending the URL work for you??

Comment: is the data sensitive? i.e. password. If not then you can append the parameter with the destination page url.

Comment: pls i am new into this and this is the first time i will be doing a challenging app using javascript, i wud av used php but the owner of the app said he doesnt want php and am 90% done except for this last part, pls can u show me how to use querystring or form or append .

Comment: @TripleDeuce, [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) will show you that very well, we can't give you more useful information than that if you don't have a specific problem. What we can do, though, is help you if you stumble upon a problem you don't understand.

Comment: how wud i append data pls

Comment: Might be worth you saying exactlty what data you are trying to pass from page to page?

Comment: am actually passing an onkeyup data from 1st page to another onkeyup data in the 2nd page and then compare the largest out of the 2 datas and then display it in another 3rd page as a statement which shows the one that is large than the other.

Comment: why have it as 3 seperate pages? seems a bit crazy

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it, you could pass a query string from page to page (prob a bad idea unless we are talking small bits of data you dont mind people seeing)

You could use local/session storage depending on the browsers you are looking to support.

You could also use a database and have a ajax post/get from page to page (not a great idea)

If you have something like php in the back end you could use a php session.

You could also use a cookie (again not the best idea but a good fallback for local/session storage)

Or you could have a single page app and use something like angular to show/change your page(s)

Comment: how wud i use query string method

Comment: MDN doc on querystrings https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/querystring

Comment: <a href="/somepage.html?data=wordupG">click me</a>

Comment: will i use METHOD="GET" with this or querrystring alone

Comment: method='get' is for a html form

Comment: i know but want to ask if i wont mk use of it in my form

Comment: if you have method='get' in a form then the form inputs will automatically be sent with the url IF they have name attributes